# Can a perceptron take real values as input or just 0 and 1?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Can perceptrons take real values as input or just 0 and 1? I am confused because the output of perceptron is 0 or 1 so I thought the input will be binary.

Comment: The output of the Perceptron being 0 or 1 is not related to the input being 0, 1. The Perceptron outputs the result of the classification. If, for your problem, it is returning 0 or 1 it means that, for a given input, it classify's it in being part (1) or not (0) of the single class you are looking at.

Comment: Regarding the output, refer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157985/neural-network-binary-vs-discrete-continuous-input). In short, if you have real-valued inputs you should only normalize them, because their are information about the particular instance you are training/classifying

Comment: None of the comments or answers are answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the basics of a perceptron process;

1. **Wight**: When a signal comes in (it can be real value), it gets multiplied by a weight value that is assigned to this particular input. That is, if a neuron has three inputs, then it has three weights that can be adjusted individually.
2. **Weighted sum**: In the next step, the modified input signals are summed up to a single value (which can be real values). In this step, an offset is also added to the sum. This offset is called bias. The neural network also adjusts the bias during the learning phase. At the start, all the neurons have random weights and random biases. After each learning iteration, weights and biases are gradually shifted so that the next result is a bit closer to the desired output. This way, the neural network gradually moves towards a state where the desired patterns are “learned”.
3. **Activation function**: Finally, the result of the neuron’s calculation is turned into an output signal by using an activation function. The heaviside step function most commonly used - it produces a binary output, 0 or 1.

You can find more info on activation functions online or have a look at this: https://sefiks.com/2017/05/15/step-function-as-a-neural-network-activation-function/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a perceptron can accept any number of real values as input, not just 0 and 1.

In addition, the output of a perceptron is not necessarily only 0 and 1. The output of a perceptron is determined by its internal "activation function." If a perceptron is outputting only a 0 or 1, it is likely using a "step function" as its activation function. Some activation functions, such as the sign function, will output either -1 or 1. You can, in theory use any activation function you wish, and [there are quite a few](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Artificial_Neural_Networks/Activation_Functions).